# How to create table with unidirectional relation in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

i have the empty database in mysql, and two java entites. One of those have unidirectional relation. When hibernate tryes to create tables, i got the error:

```
Error executing DDL "alter table entry add constraint FK6ov2k83sx3crs9v3q8nvjuf1j foreign key (category_name) references category (name)" via JDBC Statement
```

There are my entites:

```
@Entity
public class Entry {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column
    private String myfio;

    private String descr;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Category category;
}
```

And the second:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="category")
public class Category {
    @Id
    @Column
    private String name;
}
```

How to create tables without errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OneToOne relationship shares the same id. So it should be the same type, but the first one is *int* (actually it should be *Integer* to allow null value for the transient (not stored) entities) and the second one is String. It seems you simply missed a line. Also, it worths to mention Vlad Mihalchea’s article  https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetoone-relationship-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

Comment: I don't know about this detail!  I've created a new integer column in category, make it id and it's work! Thank you.